DKW Inequality and convergence in probability
Let $\hat F_n$ be the empirical CDF of a probability distribution with CDF $F$. The DKW inequality states that $$P(\Vert \hat F- F\Vert_\infty > \varepsilon) \leq 2\exp(-2n\epsilon^2).$$ I am given $\sqrt{N}\Vert \hat F_n - F\Vert_\infty$, where $N$ where is the sum of $n$ and another integer $m$ such that $\frac{n}{N}\rightarrow \lambda$ with $0<\lambda<1$ as $\min(n,m)\rightarrow\infty$.
Do I have $\sqrt N\Vert\hat F_n - F\Vert_\infty\rightarrow 0$ in probability? I would argue yes: Let $\epsilon>0$. Then $$\sqrt NP(\Vert \hat F - F\Vert_\infty>\epsilon)\leq2\sqrt N\exp(-2n\epsilon^2) = 2\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt n}\sqrt N\exp(-2n\epsilon^2) = 2\sqrt{\frac{N}{n}}\sqrt n\exp(-2n\epsilon^2).$$ Now let $\min(n,m)\rightarrow\infty$. Then $\sqrt{\frac{N}{n}}\rightarrow\frac 1\lambda$ and $\sqrt n\exp(-2n\epsilon^2)\rightarrow 0$ (as $\sqrt n\exp(-2n\epsilon^2) = \frac{n}{\exp(2n\epsilon^2)}\rightarrow 0)$. So $\sqrt NP(\Vert \hat F - F\Vert_\infty>\epsilon)\rightarrow 0$. In other words, $\Vert \hat F - F\Vert_\infty\rightarrow 0$ in probability at a faster rate than $\sqrt N\rightarrow \infty$ (as $\min(n,m)\rightarrow\infty$).
Is my reasoning correct? I am confused because if I consider $$P\left(\Vert \hat F - F\Vert_\infty>\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt N}\right)\leq 2\exp\left(-2n\frac{\epsilon^2}N\right),$$ we have that $\exp\left(-2n\frac{\epsilon^2}N\right)\rightarrow \exp(-2\lambda\epsilon^2)\neq 0$ as $\min(n,m)\rightarrow\infty$. But I guess the contradiction between both statements arises from the fact that the $\epsilon$ in the DKW is not allowed to depend on $n$. Correct?

Your first argument uses $\sqrt{N} \cdot \mathbf{P}[\text{stuff} > \varepsilon]$. Your second argument uses $\mathbf{P}[\sqrt{N} \cdot \text{stuff} > \varepsilon]$. So you're analyzing two different quantities. The second argument is the one you want, so the quantity doesn't converge to zero in probability. In fact, thinking about the central limit theorem, I think the quantity should converge in distribution to a Gaussian.

I see. Thanks for your reply
